# Is there a way to turn a specific amount of columns to rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

| A | B | C | n | n% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | randomnum1 | 0.86 |
| FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | randomnum2 | 0.6 |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | randomnum3 | 0.3 |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | randomnum4 | 0.84 |

but I would like it to look like this:

| Name | n | n% |
| --- | --- | --- |
| --- | randomnum1 | 0.86 |
| C | randomnum2 | 0.6 |
| B | randomnum3 | 0.3 |
| A | randomnum4 | 0.84 |

I'm using R but I'm fairly new to it and I couldn't find any solution online. could anyone suggest a way to restructure them?

I got the data from a google sheet and I wanted to analyse it. This is what I came up with:

```
re_eval<-datasheet %>%
  filter(a_column_from_the_sheet_with_a_value == 1)%>%
  count(endsWith(other_colum_with_string, "A"),
        endsWith(other_colum_with_string, "B"),
        endsWith(other_colum_with_string, "C"))%>%
  mutate(accuracy = round(n/reg_collection[1:4,4],3)) #this line is not important
```

Is my question clearer now? If I should add something, tell me. I'm sorry but I'm completely new to this.

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: More info on the logic please

Comment: I guess the logic is to name the rows in a way that the names comes from the original column when their value is "TRUE", i.e. first row only has FALSE, so the new row "Name" should be empty. Second row has TRUE for column B, so "Name" shoudl be B then.

Comment: I added more info

Comment: @ihavenoclueofwhatimdoing can you please rollback your edits? You are entirely changing your question so none of the answers does make sense anymore. If you want to ask a new question, create a new question.

Comment: Ok, I will try to, but Stackoverflow said I have to better my questions, thats why I did the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be not the most efficient way, but it does the job.

Note: your "n%" column does not have a proper R column name so I chose "n_pct" instead.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(F, F, F, T),
                 B = c(F, F, T, F),
                 C = c(F, T, F, F),
                 n = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 n_pct = c(0.86, 0.6, 0.3, 0.84))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B, C)) %>%
  group_by(n) %>%
  mutate(sum_value = sum(value),
         name      = if_else(sum_value == 0, "---", name),
         helper    = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(value == TRUE | (sum_value == 0 & helper == 1)) %>%
  select(name, n, n_pct)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  name      n n_pct
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ---       1  0.86
2 C         2  0.6 
3 B         3  0.3 
4 A         4  0.84
```

Comment: im sorry, I think I should have made clear, that n is random. But thank you for your help

Comment: Doesn‘t matter. The code above jusst takes the values from the original data. So whatever random value is in your original data will be carried over.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original data.frame is called df and matches this one

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), B = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), C = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), n = 1:4, 
    `n%` = c(0.86, 0.6, 0.3, 0.84)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
#       A     B     C n   n%
# 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE 1 0.86
# 2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE 2 0.60
# 3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE 3 0.30
# 4  TRUE FALSE FALSE 4 0.84
```

You can create a new data frame with a Name column by using `max.col` and `rowSums`. The output of `max.col(df[1:3])` is the column-index of the max value in the first three columns of `df`. However, if they're all false you want to return `NA` instead of some random index. So check if they're all `NA` by checking if they sum to `0`.

```
new_df <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = names(df)[ifelse(rowSums(df[1:3]) == 0, NA, max.col(df[1:3]))])
```

Then add the other colunms to this new data.frame

```
new_df[2:3] <- df[-(1:3)]

new_df
#   Name n   n%
# 1 <NA> 1 0.86
# 2    C 2 0.60
# 3    B 3 0.30
# 4    A 4 0.84
```